# Using jQuery to hide a multiselect

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select

I have an html select DOM object by simply coding the raw html `<select ...`

I then use javascript and jQuery to change that select into a 'multiselect' object by using code like this...

```
$("#myselectid").multiselect();
```

And later on some event, I am trying to hide that multiselect with jQuery code like this...

```
$("#myselectid").hide()
```

But that does not work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on jsfiddle? or even at least paste your full code.

Comment: If you did in fact get the selector right, and that's just a typo, I'm guessing the plugin creates an unordered list, or some other element, instead of the select element and you're not targeting that element.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Give this a shot? - `$("ui-multiselect").hide(); $("ui-multiselect-menu").hide();`

Comment: Just wrap it in a div e.g. mydiv and then you can use $("#mydiv").hide();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiselect hides the original select and then it creates a button with the select behavior

Try

```
$("#myselectid").next().hide()
```

And it will hide that select that is created

Take a look at this [page](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm)

if you do a

```
$("select:eq(0)")
```

That element is already hide but the one that you see is the next one (a button) try:

```
$("select:eq(0)").next()
```

You need to hide this one, that is the one created by multiselect

Comment: Ahm you don't have the next i don't see it o.o

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue!

Comment: Yw I'm glad I could help you